# How to integrate Paubox with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I try to integrate Paubox with Laravel 5 as custom mail provider.
How can I do it in best way?
I installed https://github.com/Paubox/paubox-php bot there is no description how to connect it with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by creating new service provider and Transport class.

1. Change default mail service provider in config/app.php:

```php
// Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\PauboxServiceProvider::class,
```

2. Add credentials to config/mail.php:

```php
'pauboxApiKey' => env('PAUBOX_API_KEY'),
'pauboxApiUser' => env('PAUBOX_API_USER')
```

3. Changes in .env

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=paubox
PAUBOX_API_KEY=
PAUBOX_API_USER=
```

4. Create new service provider app/Providers/PauboxServiceProvider.php

```php
<?php 
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider;
class PauboxServiceProvider extends MailServiceProvider { 
    protected function registerSwiftTransport() {
        $this->app->singleton('swift.transport', function ($app) {
            return new PauboxTransportManager($app);
        });   
    } 
}
```

5. Create transport manager app/Providers/PauboxTransportManager.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager;
class PauboxTransportManager extends TransportManager {
    protected function createPauboxDriver() {
        return new PauboxTransport;
    }
}
```

6. Create transport app/Providers/PauboxTransport.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\Transport;
use Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage;
use App\Vendors\Paubox as Paubox;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnprocessableEntityHttpException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class PauboxTransport extends Transport {
    protected $config;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->config = config('mail');
    }

    public function send(Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage $msg, &$failedRecipients = null) {
        $paubox = new Paubox\Paubox($this->config['pauboxApiUser'], $this->config['pauboxApiKey']);

        $message = new Paubox\Mail\Message();
        $content = new Paubox\Mail\Content();
        $header = new Paubox\Mail\Header();

        $content->setHtmlText($msg->getBody());

        $header->setSubject($msg->getSubject());
        $header->setFrom('"' . $this->config['from']['name'] . '" <' . $this->config['from']['address'] . '>');
        $header->setReplyTo($this->config['from']['address']);

        $recipients = [];
        foreach ($msg->getTo() as $to => $val) {
            recipients[] = $to;
        }

        $message->setHeader($header);
        $message->setContent($content);
        $message->setRecipients($recipients);

        $sendMessageResponse = new Paubox\Mail\SendMessageResponse();
        $sendMessageResponse = $paubox->sendMessage($message);
        $errorMsg = '';
        if (isset($sendMessageResponse->errors)) {
            foreach ($sendMessageResponse->errors as $error) {
                $errorMsg .= json_encode($error);
            }
            Log::error(PHP_EOL . "Paubox: " . $errorMsg . PHP_EOL);
            throw new UnprocessableEntityHttpException('Error occurred while sending email');
        }
        return $sendMessageResponse;
    }
}
```

7. I copied https://github.com/Paubox/paubox-php into App\Vendors\Paubox. I had to do it bacause paubox installed with composer didn't read my .env data. After copy I had to change namespaces in all files, and add Paubox constructor to pass api_key and api_user:

```php
public function __construct($pauboxApiUser, $pauboxApiKey)
    {
        $this->pauboxApiUser = $pauboxApiUser;
        $this->pauboxApiKey = $pauboxApiKey;
    }
```

and below in code:

change `\getenv('PAUBOX_API_USER');`
into `$this->pauboxApiUser;`

and change `\getenv('PAUBOX_API_KEY');`
into `$this->pauboxApiKey;`

A had to also install `composer require nategood/httpful`